# Ubuntu 17.10 No external connections outside of localhost

Tags: networking, apache2, 17.10, ufw

I've been pulling my hair out over this issue for the past 8 hours, and I cannot for the life of me find the issue.

I have a brand new installation of Ubuntu 17.10 on a machine which I've installed apache2 on. When I try to connect to the server on localhost, I get the Ubuntu test page like normal. But when I try to connect from anywhere outside of localhost, I get nothing. Whatever browser I'm using simply states the connection has timed out.

I've tried pinging the server, and the ping gets through. Every other machine on my network can receive traffic on port 80, so that rules out issues with the router. UFW is inactive, so I don't see how it could be interfering. I've even tried switching to a different OS on the same machine, and it works when I switch OS, but it will not work with 17.10.

I'm at my wit's end at this point, and I'm not sure what to do from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

General troubleshooting of networking stack as follows:

1. First of all check on your service is running and listening on network socket (interface) i.e ipaddress and port number. By running the following:

   ```
   netstat -lanp | grep apache2
   ```
2. Note the ip address and port number from above command.In my case that's

   ```
   tcp6       0      0 :::80               :::*              LISTEN      12253/apache2  
   tcp6       0      0 :::443              :::*              LISTEN      12253/apache2
   ```
3. Try to telnet on into your socket from another machine

   ```
   telnet ipaddress_ofyour_apache_host 80
   ```

   you should get

   ```
   Trying ipaddress_ofyour_apache_host..
   Connected to ipaddress_ofyour_apache_host
   ```
4. If you get connected that's meaning that on os network level is everything working fine no firewall is blocking or other issues
5. If you still don't get a welcome page from apache go ahead and check apparmor and for purpose of checking disable it temporarily

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop apparmor.service
   sudo update-rc.d -f apparmor remove
   ```
6. Check again from your web browser if you still don't get a page go ahead and check apache2 access.log

Comment: The service is running, and I get `tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      7557/apache2 ` when I run netstat. Telnet simply says "no route to host," even after disabling apparmor.  The access.log doesn't have any  idea I'm trying to connect, it only has connections from localhost listed inside of it. This would suggest a routing issue, but I don't get it because I just reset the router to factory defaults, and every other machine has no problem with port 80. It's just this one.

Comment: Actually, scratch the part about telnet giving "no route to host." I was using the wrong address on accident. It actually just sits there for a long time before saying "Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out."

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is fixed, but unfortunately I can't explain precisely why. I had a static mapping to the server in the router, and I guess the server didn't like it. I switched the server's IP address, and it seems to be functioning normally.